# Get rid of "?" and "use arrow keys" when using inquirer.js

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using inquirer.js to make a little CLI game, but when i use prompts it will show `?` and `(use arrow keys)` in the console, i've looked everywhere and can't find a solution. any help would be very appreciated!
current code:

```js
async question1() {
    const answers = await inquirer.prompt({
        name: 'question1',
        type: 'list',
        message: '\n',
        choices: [
            'Answer 1',
            'Answer 2',
            'Answer 3',
        ],        
    })

    return answers.question1;
}
```

I tried looking in the docs and expected some sort of config for the prompts but didn't find anything of the sort.

Comment: FYI about the "use arrow keys" string, I think there is an enhancement request : https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/issues/1016#issuecomment-849981824

Comment: @MaximeBaker I had a look at the code (the file linked in that enhancement request) a few minutes ago and noticed the code he suggested was already in there. But for some odd reason it doesn't want to work in my code. 